# Disable DevExpress / VassistX by default?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, devexpress, visual-assist

Is there any way to prevent start/load of DevExpress and/or Vissual assist?
Even if disabling it's up'n running the next time.

When using a limited cpu larger projects sometimes freezes everything for a bunch of minutes each time you forget to disable (and seems like I forget it each time).

Tried both out and one of them could be a nice contribute, if disabled by default.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I cannot tell you about VAssist, but automatic loading of CodeRush is controlled by the DevExpress--> Options-->Core-->Startup-->Load manually option.

Comment: That helped me find it. The option showed up when the configuration mode was set expert. thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find the Startup option under Core; till I changed the Level to Expert from New User

Answer (score 0):

To load it up again, you can go to Tools->Load DevExpress.

To bring up the options page, do Ctrl+Alt+Shift+O and change it to expert mode in bottom left pane.